# after using mod_rewrite link are not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was changed my url from

`http://example.com/admin/courses.php?id=1001`

to

`http://example.com/articles/1001`

usig this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    admin/courses.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

but after changing the url, all the css, images, js link of course.php page is automatically change from

```
http://example.com/admin/css/style.css
```

to

```
http://example.com/articles/css/style.css
```

I need to help

Comment: Google for `RewriteLog` - it will print debug information about the ruleset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the assets to be requested correctly? I guess you're using incorrect relative paths for linking those in your page's code (something like "images/image.jpg"..). If that's the folder structure you have, try to go one level up and use this path:

```
<img src="../admin/images/image.jpg" ...
```

or, in the case you specified:

```
<link href="../admin/css/style.css" ...
```

Comment: your answer is write but it increase the lots of work for changing all of href and src

Comment: you can always use your IDE's search and replace functionality to prepend that ../admin faster or even multi line selection. additionally, you can build your base url with a php variable, so you only have to change it in one place next time you decide to rewrite again

Answer (score 1):

The `?` needs to be escaped and `id=` added:

```
RewriteRule articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/\?id=$    admin/courses.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
#                             -------^
```

Comment: sir can you explain please I am not understand what you want to say

Comment: i use this code and url like this http://example.com/articles/1001 but it given 404